# Помогите понять работу деревьев на примере ИИ для крестиков-ноликов

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, дерево, искусственный-интеллект

Здравствуйте! Стало интересно узнать, как работает ИИ в играх, начать было решено с крестиков ноликов, по понятным причинам.

Сразу был придуман такой алгоритм -

1. Находим все возможные ходы (на этом шаге можно убрать те ходы, которые можно получить из уже существующих поворотом поля, но можно этого и не делать)
2. Для каждого возможного хода выполняем

   - Если следующий ход приводит к победе, выполняем его
   - Если нет, **просчитываем в глубину** все возможные исходы игры после этого хода, запоминаем отношение количества выигранных партий к числу возможных (обзовем этот параметр `prob`)
3. Выбираем ход, с самым большим значением `prob`

Первые два пункта реализуются легко, а вот дальше начинаются сложности, связанные, скорее всего, с непониманием устройства деревьев. Не могли бы вы объяснить, и, желательно показать, как представить игру в виде дерева? Как потом его обойти, вроде бы, понятно, хотя комментарий к этому пункту тоже желателен. Язык не так важен, но лучше с++.

---

Получился вот такой код:

```
class GameTree
{
private:
  vector<GameTree> children;
  vector<int> probs;
  Board current;
public:
  GameTree(Board board, int totalP, int currentP, int depth = 0)
  {
    for(int i=1; i<totalP+1; i++) // если кто-то уже выиграл, нудно перестать считать
      if(board.isWonBy(i))
      {
        cout<<"\t\t\t\twon by "<<i<<endl;
        return;
      }

      if(currentP == totalP+1)
        currentP = 1;

      cout<<"Depth = "<<depth<<endl;
      cout<<"Player = "<<currentP<<endl;
      cout<<"Board: "<< endl;
      board.print();
      getchar();

      current = board;

      vector<Move> avalMoves = current.avalMoves();

      for(int i=0; i<avalMoves.size(); i++)
      {
        children.push_back(
        GameTree(current.withMove(avalMoves[i].withPlayer(currentP)),
        totalP, currentP+1, depth+1));
      }
  }
};

class Board
{
private:
  int N;
  int size;
  int *board;

  int toN(int x, int y)
  {
    return y*N+x;
  }

public:
  Board(int *prev = NULL, int n = 2)
  {
    N = n;
    size = (int)pow(3, N);
    board = new int[size];

    if(prev == NULL)
      for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            board[i] = 0;

    else
      for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
      {
        board[i] = prev[i];
      }
  }

  bool isWonBy(int p)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
      if(board[Move(i, 0).toN()] == p &&
         board[Move(i, 1).toN()] == p &&
         board[Move(i, 2).toN()] == p)
      {
        return true;

      }

      if(board[Move(0, i).toN()] == p &&
         board[Move(1, i).toN()] == p &&
         board[Move(2, i).toN()] == p)
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    if(board[Move(0, 0).toN()] == p &&
       board[Move(1, 1).toN()] == p &&
       board[Move(2, 2).toN()] == p)
      {
        return true;
      }

    if(board[Move(0, 2).toN()] == p &&
       board[Move(1, 1).toN()] == p &&
       board[Move(2, 0).toN()] == p)
      {
        return true;
      }

    return false;
  }

  vector<Move> avalMoves()
  {
    vector<Move> ret;

    for(int i=0; i<pow(3, N); i++)
      if(board[i] == 0)
      {
        ret.push_back(Move(i));
      }

    return ret;
  }

  void applyMove(Move move)
  {
    if(board[move.toN()] == 0)
      board[move.toN()] = move.getPlayer();
  }

  Board withMove(Move move)
  {
    Board ret(board, N);
    ret.applyMove(move);
    return ret;
  }

  void print()
  {
    for(int x=0; x<3; x++)
    {
      for(int y=0; y<3; y++)
      {
        cout<<board[Move(x, y).toN()]<<' ';
      }

      cout<<endl;
    }
  }
};

class Move
{
private:
  int player;
  int x;
  int y;

public:
  Move(int x_, int y_)
  {
    player = -1;
    x = x_;
    y = y_;
    null = false;
  }

  Move(int i)
  {
    player = -1;
    x = i%(int)pow(3, 2-1); // TODO 2 сменить на N
    y = i/(int)pow(3, 2-1);
  }

  int setPlayer(int p)
  {
    player = p;
  }

  int getPlayer()
  {
    return player;
  }

  Move withPlayer(int i)
  {
    Move ret(x, y);
    ret.setPlayer(i);
    return ret;
  }

  int toN()
  {
    return y*2+x;
  }
};
```

Вызывается все это так:

```
int main()
{
    Board b;
    GameTree(b, 2, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Depth = 0
Player = 1
Board:
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

Depth = 1
Player = 2
Board:
1 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

Depth = 2
Player = 1
Board:
1 0 0
2 0 0
0 0 0

Depth = 3
Player = 2
Board:
1 1 0
2 0 0
1 0 0

Depth = 4
Player = 1
Board:
1 1 0
2 0 0
1 0 0
```

После этого повторяется последнее состояние. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: простое гугление показывает как [сделать дерево в с++](http://hci.fenster.name/304y/lab3/). Там правда дерево бинарное, но это не проблема - нужно просто сделать массив вместо двух полей. А как игру представить в виде дерева - это дело такое. Но наверное, логически было бы вершина - это состояние, а ребро - это ход.

Comment: С моей точки зрения у вас неправильная функция оценки. Почитайте вот эту -- "Корнилов - Программирование шахмат и других логических игр" -- книгу, может быть для вас что либо прояснится.